# Are there good examples of requiring open data in RFPs?

Tags: usa, best-practice

The recent U.S. Executive Order on open and machine-readable data requires the U.S. government to begin developing ways to integrate open data into procurement and grant-making.

Are there good examples (i.e. clear, simple, and re-usable language) in other government jurisdictions (local, state, or outside U.S.) where the government entity is requiring the output of the procurement or grant to be delivered as open data?

Comment: I think you want to do two things for maximum impact in the long-term: require open data, and require interoperability.

Essentially you want to require open data because it's the public's data. You want to require interoperability so it's easy to fire the incumbents.

Answer (score 3):

Clear and simple, I can do ... re-usable I'm not so sure of.

NSF in 2011 put a requirement on all [grant applications to submit a 'data management plan'](http://www.nsf.gov/eng/general/dmp.jsp), explaining what data would be produced and made available by the project.  Note that it doesn't actually require the data to be 'open', and it's entirely possible that the scope of the project may be such that the PIs believe that there isn't any 'data' produced.**

There's also been questions as to what instructions NSF has been giving to the grant review panels about data management plans, and how much weight they have in the final scoring of the grant proposals.

NASA has various 'data policy' statements, depending on the field.  The [heliophysics policy](http://hpde.gsfc.nasa.gov/Heliophysics_Data_Policy_2009Apr12.html) states:

> Two overarching principles also essential to achieving the goals of current Heliophysics programs are:
>
> 1. Embracing NASA's open data policy that high-quality, high-resolution data, as defined by the mission goals, will be made publicly available as soon as practical ...

... while the [NASA Earth science policy](http://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/earth-science-data/data-information-policy/) contains:

> - NASA commits to the full and open sharing of Earth science data obtained from NASA Earth observing satellites, sub-orbital platforms and field campaigns with all users as soon as such data become available.
> - There will be no period of exclusive access to NASA Earth science data. Following a post-launch checkout period, all data will be made available to the user community. Any variation in access will result solely from user capability, equipment, and connectivity.
> - NASA will make available all NASA-generated standard products along with the source code for algorithm software, coefficients, and ancillary data used to generate these products.
> - All NASA Earth science missions, projects, and grants and cooperative agreements shall include data management plans to facilitate the implementation of these data principles.
> - NASA will enforce a principle of non-discriminatory data access so that all users will be treated equally. For data products supplied from an international partner or another agency, NASA will restrict access only to the extent required by the appropriate Memorandum of Understanding (MOU).

My understanding is that all NASA missions require a 'PDMP' (project data management plan)

** although, that then gets us into the question of what is 'data', which is much too long and off-topic for this post.

(Disclaimer : I work for a NASA heliophysics archive; I haven't served on a grant review panel for years and never for NSF)

Answer (score 3):

The U.S. Department of Education (ED) has added open data language to several RFPs and grant competitions.

- For a grant example, see http://www.ed.gov/race-top/district-competition/definitions (or  which includes definitions for 'open data format', 'open-standard registry', and 'interoperable data system'.

As a result of the recent Executive Order (http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2013/05/09/executive-order-making-open-and-machine-readable-new-default-government-), additional guidance including templates for acquisition language will be forthcoming.

- For an RFP (an interim example statement) may be: "In support of Executive Order – “Making Open and Machine Readable the New Default for Government Information”, the Contractor shall provide data in open and machine readable formats (e.g., CSV, XML, JSON, API) that would allow stakeholders to leverage data developed to promote widespread use and dissemination. For existing examples, please visit http://www.{{agencyname}}.gov/developer webpage."